# Angular Directive cannot access scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm not well experienced in angular js and your help desperately!

I'm trying to create a tab navigation for angular based website.

Here is my html:

```
<body ng-app = "app">
    <div class="bottom-content-container">
        <form class = "tab-nav">
            <tab-nav nav = "popular"></tab-nav>
            <tab-nav nav = "recent"></tab-nav>
        </form>

        <div class="tab-content" ng-switch = "tab">
            <div ng-switch-when = "popular">
                Popular Images
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when = "recent">
                Recent Images
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

And here is the js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('tabNav', function () {
  return {
    template : '<label> <input type="radio" ng-model="tab" value="{{nav}}" name = "tabnav" /><span>{{nav}}</span></label>',
    replace:true,
    scope:{
      nav: '@'
    }
  };
});
```

The thing probably is that I'm messing up the scopes, and the directive is not changing the "tab" variable, so nothing happens.

Here is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zefifeyozi/edit?html,js,console,output)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Very good question, I am having the same problem .. waiting for the answer  :s

Comment: I think you want to change `value="{{nav}}"` to `value="{{tab}}"` because you model is tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/vojile/edit?html,js,output)

I found a solution ! Don't know what's the negative sides of it, but works fine !

I'm passing the tab to tab-nav and works nice (y)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're making a copy of the "tab" value in the child's scope and not using the parent one.

Comment: Then why does the parent change on nav click?

Comment: Because it's a reference to the same object. Inside the directive the following returns true: "tab === $parent.tab"

Answer (score 2):

I've made a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wixuzusiyi/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

In the directive scope @ is used to bind to attributes, as your directive should set a selected value that will be read from outside you need to use =. Then I wrap everything insde a ctrl to hold this selected value so your content can use it to display the tabs.

Comment: You're making a redundant copy of the parent's scope value with this part:
tab="vm.selectedTab"

Comment: What do you mean? Please can you be more concise. I know that it's not the most optimal solution

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how passing "tab" into the directive and declaring it with "=" both work (IMO only one of them should be used), but your solution involves copying the value from the parent scope and making a separate one in the isolated scope. I could be mistaken of course, it's best to check with some debugger like ng-inspector: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/

Comment: The same check as in the other solutions points to this: "tab === $parent.tab" inside the directive evaluates to true.

Comment: I don't think that accessing $parent is a good approach, the purpose of directives is code reuse and accesing parents it's not a good apprach, because you don't know if later parent will change.

Comment: Yes, that's what the tab: '=' does, (AKA two way binding). If $parent.tab used, you no longer need : tab: '='  line in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tab-nav ng-click="tab='popular'" nav = "popular"></tab-nav>
  <tab-nav ng-click="tab='recent'" nav = "recent"></tab-nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `$parent`:

```
app.directive('tabNav', function () {
  return {
    template : '<label> <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.tab" value="{{nav}}" name = "tabnav" /><span>{{nav}}</span></label>',
    replace:true,
    scope:{
      nav: '@',
      tab : '='
    }
  };
});
```

Also notice how the `value` property is bound.